# How to distinguish healthy tree points and deadwood points in point cloud?

Tags: python, gis, point-clouds

Everyone

I'm now doing point cloud processing in the area of Geographic information system.

What I wanna do is to get the percentage of healthy trees in a point cloud. My idea is to use RGB value in the .las file to do this job. But I found it's hard to find the threshold of RGB values. And now, I'm going to try logistic regression. Yet, in this case, I have to label the data point manually. I think it would be okay but I'm worrying about if this is robust or reliable.

Could someone studying in this area help me out? No need to tell me how to do it. I just a correct and feasible approach in python. Thanks a lot.

Rowen

Comment: What exactly is the strongest cue for health in your tree data? [For human eye]

Comment: @3yanlis1bos Color is the cue. Healthy tree point is green. Maybe I should define a range of leaf green? But my programme is not only applied to one dataset. Is that fine?

Comment: It depends on the color of the other class. It would be fine if you have, say, black as the color of dead trees. If your program should adapt itself/give OK results for many datasets, then you should find a feature then can be generalized on these data too. **why dont you try providing some visual examples?**

Comment: Hello, guys. I've finally handle the problem. In my case, I convert the RGB value into HSV and compare it with a color range. But be careful when set the color ranges. It may vary from different seasons, light, and UAV and etc.